# Issues typing "Illegal Unicode Characters"

Tags: java, unicode, focus, clipboard

Well I need to write a few strange unicode characters in this program  is an example of one of them. Firstly I tried using a robot to write it but there is no

```
VK_(The Character)
```

and KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED made no sense to me. I tried

```
r.keyPress(18);
```

and

```
char res = "".charAt(0);
        r.keyPress(res);
        r.keyRelease(res);
```

Still no luck
So I finally came up with a workaround.

```
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(color);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, null);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.delay(30);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
```

Simply adding it to the clipboard and copy paste. (color is the variable name for the symbol) The only issue is that this program overlays another. (The use is a little strange) The other program is fullscreen and I don't like the start bar popping up everytime this program is clicked.

```
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
    setFocusable(false);
    jPanel1.setFocusable(false);
    jButton1.setFocusable(false);
    jButton2.setFocusable(false);
    jButton3.setFocusable(false);
    jButton4.setFocusable(false);
    jButton5.setFocusable(false);
    jButton6.setFocusable(false);
    jButton7.setFocusable(false);
    jButton8.setFocusable(false);
    jButton9.setFocusable(false);
    jButton10.setFocusable(false);
    jButton11.setFocusable(false);
```

This was my solution. It works great except setFocusableWindowState(false); for some reason disables my premissions to change the clipboard. The rest of the program works. So I am asking for help and the way I see it there are 2 solutions.  Changing how the program types the unicode character. OR Find some way to modify the clipboard contents when the program is set as setFocusableWindowState(false);

Comment: Robots are supposed to mimic user behavior. How would you have produced that character if you were doing it rather than the robot?

Comment: You have a very good point there. It actually gave me an idea too. Well I tried my idea. I tried using the alt code Alt+0012. Nothing comes up. Thats the character I want. [link](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) `Alt Codes`[/link]

Comment: That's a control character that's virtually never used... Did you succeed in producing it yourself using the alt key? What did it produce on screen?

Comment: When I tried to produce it with the alt code it made a ding noise and nothing happened. How I came up with the unicode character originally was that I used a hex editor,typed it in then opened in notepad. I either need another way to make that work. Or to find out why the clipboard doesn't work with setFocusaleWindowState(false);

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to do there. I'm getting the feeling it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and that you are trying to do something that you shouldn't be doing with a robot anyway. Perhaps you should expand your question to explain the background.

Comment: Well I am trying to make it output a certain character [link]http://prntscr.com/6zoe6f[/link] Like to type it outside of the program. For example if I had my program open and notepad open. I would like to be able to click notepad. Then click my program without notepad losing focus. Then for my program to type that symbol. My current solution is to use clipboard then robot to copy paste. But I can't do this without focus for some reason. Using robot to Alt+Tab back to notepad in this example is not exactly what I am looking for either.

Comment: But *why* do you want to type that symbol? That's not a printable symbol. If you copied it from a hex editor, it's probably a stand-in character, rather than the real character. What is the purpose of this? And please - add additional information to your *question*, not to the comments.